# \includegraphics: a command in the optional argument

Tags: graphics, expansion

I want to pass some arguments to `\includegraphics` via a command, but I can't get it working as I would expect. My M(n)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\widthText}{,width=3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5 \widthText]{picture}

\end{document}
```

I guess that the point would be to expand `\widthText` before...

In my actual code, the command `\widthText` is actually either the one given above, or empty, depending on some boolean, and I have also a `\heightText` to set the height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Staying with the desire of the OP, here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\includeGraphics{\@testopt\roy@includegraphics{}}
\def\roy@includegraphics[#1]#2{%
  \begingroup
  % Every expandable token in #1 may be expanded here:
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[#1]}\x{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\widthText}{,width=3cm}
% Since double comma (,,) in the key-value pairs doesn't hurt both keyval and 
% xkeyval packages, and since the user of \widthText might forget to insert
% a comma before 'width', let us add a potentially redundant comma in the 
% following:
\includeGraphics[viewport=20 21 590 400,scale=0.5, \widthText]{./Graphics/comet1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The keyval system used by graphicx goes to some trouble not to expand macros while parsing, so that the macros can be used as the *values* of the keys. the intended usage is more like

```
\newcommand{\widthText}{\ifsomething 3cm \else \Gin@nat@width \fi}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5, width=\widthText]{picture}
```

where `\Gin@nat@width` is the natural width.

My original answer suggested `\width` could be used, thanks for the correction in the comments. `\Gin@nat@width` works, but means that your definition has to be in a package or inside `\makeatletter...` In the following, the first two are equivalent, the second is scaled to half size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\fbox{\includegraphics[]{fj.png}}


\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\Gin@nat@width]{fj.png}}


\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\Gin@nat@width]{fj.png}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `\ifsomething` do/mean? Or: When is `\ifsomething` expanded to true?

Comment: `\ifsomething` is just a placeholder because the OP said it depended on an (unstated) condition. It could be `\ifodd\year...` to scale one way or the other in alternate years, or whatever is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately `\includegraphics` doesn't accept `\width` as an argument of `width`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, doesn't it? who implemented that?:-), I'm sure it was supposed to, will check and revise answer...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Will give a problem if you wanted to pass for example "keepaspectratio".

Comment: @MartinScharrer, thanks, answer fixed/tested this time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Have a look at my comp.text.tex post [Using \width, \height and \totalwidth for 'width', 'height' and 'totalheight' arguments of \includegraphics](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/-BcLDoctZfk/IhNKBObDnfYJ). It will work with my `adjustbox` package, btw.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, yes exactly, I could have sworn it did that, but apparently not. I think the implementation in TeX didn't in the end match the implementation in my head, and of course I only remember the latter.

Comment: I'm having problems doing this with a `[page=\thecounter]` argument to be passed, even though I think your answer indicates that it should work.  Or is there a problem because its a counter, not a length?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\thecounter` is the print form of the counter so may have other text (and prefix numbers) If it expands to an integer it should work, put \page=\value{counter} is better anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The code handling the key=value pairs must be able to see the separating comma, therefore it must not be included in a macro. You either need to expand the content of the macro manually or feed it to `\includegraphics` in another way. For the first method you can use `\expandafter` or `\edef`.

There is also my `adjustbox` package which provides the keys `min width` and `max width`, either using `\adjincludegraphics[<key options>]{<filename>}` or `\adjustimage{<key option>}{<filename>}` or by loading the package with the `export` option which makes all new key options available to the normal `\includegraphics`. I think this might also help you depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Will you please post a minimal?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand clearly from your answer, wether with `adjsutbox`, i can hide the commas in a macro or not.

Comment: @nicolasroy: `adjustbox` doesn't expand the keys as well, so no you can't hide them in a macro. However, you seem to want to set the width depending on some external influence. If this is to enforce a minimal or maximal width, then the given keys can solve your underlying problem better than using a macro.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way and it works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\def\test#1{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5,#1]{picture}}
\test{width=3cm}\par
\test{width=1cm}

\def\keepaspectratio{keepaspectratio}
\test{width=1cm,height=3cm,\keepaspectratio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You then could use something like `\expandafter\test\expandafter{\widthText}` to insert the expanded macro content in the right place.

Comment: @Yiannis: The definition `\def\keepaspectratio{keepaspectratio}` amounts to submitting a macro as a key name. This is not advisable and might not work always, depending on the type of key and whether it carries pointers.

Comment: @AhmedMusa You know better about this sort of thing. What would you recommend?

Comment: The *graphicx* package ordinarily uses `\setkeys` from the *keyval* package. So, because key macro names are built using `\csname`, there will be no problem when a key name is given as a macro (as in your case). However, when *xkeyval* package is loaded, its `\setkeys` will automatically be used. This `\setkeys` is more complicated and does some internal checks that will be impossible if the key name is hidden in a macro. Hence key-value pairs should be expanded before they’re given as an argument of `\setkeys`.

Comment: When expanding key-value pairs, some caution is necessary when the keys carry pointers: the two pointers of xkeyval package are undefined. Also, the 'value' part of a key-value pair may contain yet-to-be-defined macros, or macros that shouldn't be expanded prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Not an aswer but maybe an alternative way …

If you want to predefine some keys you can seth them with `\setkeys{Gin}{<options>}`. These keys can be overwritten locally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\setkeys{Gin}{width=4cm,height=2cm}


\begin{document}
\includegraphics{file1}

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{file1}
\end{document}
```

Note: This work not with all options, e.g. using `scale`in `\setkeys` won’t give the desired result.

Comment: Note that `\setkeys{Gin}{..}` only works with some but not all `\includegraphics` options, depending on how they are handled internally. However, `width` and `height` will work, but not `scale`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I forgot to mention this while writing my answer O:-) I had the problem with `scale` some time ago …

Comment: The `adjustbox` package offers a way to set all options globally. See the the manual for more.