# Using setkeys for a specific graphic -- or: How to define options for a specific graphic in a command or macro?

Tags: includegraphics

*(The motivation for my question is given at the end!)*

**Question:**
How can I define keys for the options of `includegraphics` in a separate command, i.e., not directly in the graphic that uses them? (E.g., so that the same options can be used multiple times, or so you can simply define them centrally rather than at the graphic inclusion itself.)

Note that `graphicx` allows you to define a *standard* for these options that is used for all graphics unless you override them by specifying new ones. This this done with the setkeys command and it looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkeys{Gin}{width=4cm,height=4cm}

\begin{document}   
  \hspace*{-3cm}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=!]{example-image-c}
  \includegraphics[width=!,height=!]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, the first graphic you see uses the *new* standard of 4cm/4cm, whereas the others override them with individual values (w/h):

- A: 4cm/4cm, the new standard
- B: 2cm/4cm, because height is still the new standard
- C: 2cm/*, where * is the height in the right relation to width
- image: */*, i.e., the original measures of the graphic

I, however, would like to use the setkeys definition only for a specific graphic! (Of course I could set a new standard and use for every other graphic `width` and `height` with `!`, but that is obviously not an acceptable solution.) I.e., I do *not* want to have the standard changed, but I would like to be able to use this definition only in a(ny) graphic of my choice! E.g., I would like to be able to something like

```
\setkeys{MyKeys}{width=4cm,height=4cm}
..
\includegraphics[MyKeys]{example-image-X}
```

Is that possible, somehow?

**Motivation:**

I would like to define my own package (i.e., a sty file) for beamer slides that should be flexible enough so that, for most cases, people using it don't have to touch it anymore. Instead, all necessary editing/individualization should be done in a separate configuration file. (Where you can, for example, define the title and author for the title slide.)

One of those things that should be configured there is the size of the graphic that appears in the title slide. Thus, *in principle*, the sty file should contain something like: `\includegraphics[\OptionsSpecifiedInConfigFile]{\LogoSpecifiedInConfigFile}`. However, these options (like `width=2cm,height=3cm`) cannot simply be stored in a command (like `\OptionsSpecifiedInConfigFile`), so I require a different solution.

I know that passing on options to my package could also be an option (which I do already!), but doing this for these options in particular does not make sense I believe.

**Related stackoverflow posts:**

- [Using scale in setkeys does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297682/scale-in-graphicx-don%C2%B4t-work-when-width-set-with-setkeys)
- [Specifying options for includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46623/includegraphics-a-command-in-the-optional-argument)

(They did not help me solve my issue, but they still seem highly related, so I posted them in case others deem them useful.)

***Thank you for your help!***

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but couldn't you define something like `\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm, #1]{#2}}` and use that when you want your new defaults?

Comment: Indeed, that would work, thank you! I am clueless why I did not see that... Would you like to post that as an answer (I'm happy to improve it to match the exact scenario from above). I am still curious, though, whether there is a more elegant solution in which one just defines those keys (so that one key-definition can be re-used several times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a different default for some cases, you can define a new command for that

```
\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm, #1]{#2}}
```

---

If you want to save the options in a special macro you need to expand the macro before it is passed to `\includegraphics`

```
\newcommand*{\OptionsSpecifiedInConfigFile}{width=4cm,height=4cm}
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\OptionsSpecifiedInConfigFile]{example-image-a}
```

Comment: Once more: Thanks a lot! Against my expectation (because you did not mention this in the comment above), you even added a "nicer" variant where only the keys get defined, nice! :)